# How would i go about, making it so that when i log in on the index.html page it goes through to the sql database like it does in the other scripts

Tags: php, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I'm only just beginning to learn how to program, and most of this code isn't original they are from tutorials and stuff. I am using it to learn how it all goes together.

I've been having trouble with implementing the php and mysql scripts into the main HTML page.

** Ive been using WAMP

This is the index.html

---

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
        <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and 
media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

    <style type="text/css">
      .box{
        background-color: #d3d3d3;
        border: 1px solid grey;
      }

    </style>

      </head>
      <body>

        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">

          <div class="container">

            <div class="navbar-header">

              <a href="" class="navbar-brand">Insanity and Calamity</a>

              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">

                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>

              </button>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">

              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="">Andrew</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Tommy</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Jayme</a></li>
              </ul>
               <ul class="nav pull-right">
              <li><a href="register.php">Sign Up</a></li>
              <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Sign In <strong class="caret"></strong></a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" style="padding: 15px; padding-bottom: 0px;">

            <form action="login.php" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                <input id="user_username" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" type="text" name="user[username]" size="30" />
                <input id="user_password" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" type="password" name="user[password]" size="30" />
                 <input id="user_remember_me" style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;" type="checkbox" name="user[remember_me]" value="1" />
                 <label class="string optional" for="user_remember_me"> Remember me</label>

                <input class="btn btn-primary" style="clear: left; width: 100%; height: 32px; font-size: 13px;" type="submit" name="commit" value="Sign In" />
            </form>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


       <h1>Hello, world!</h1>



        <div class="container">

          <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-6 box">Holy cow</div>
            <div class="col-md-6 box">Holy cow</div>

          </div>
          <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-4 box">Holy cow is super cool</div>
            <div class="col-md-4 box">Holy cow is super cool</div>
            <div class="col-md-4 box">Holy cow is super cool</div>

          </div>

        </div>
        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

the login.php

---

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>User Login Form - PHP MySQL Ligin System | W3Epic.com</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>User Login Form - PHP MySQL Ligin System | W3Epic.com</h1>
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])){
?>
<!-- The HTML login form -->
    <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
        Username: <input type="text" name="username" />
        Password: <input type="password" name="password" />

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
<?php
} else {
    require_once("db_const.php");
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    # check connection
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->connect_errno} : {$mysqli->connect_error}</p>";
        exit();
    }

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $sql = "SELECT * from users WHERE username LIKE '{$username}' AND password LIKE '{$password}' LIMIT 1";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    if (!$result->num_rows == 1) {
        echo "<p>Invalid username/password combination</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>Logged in successfully</p>";
        // do stuffs
    }
}
?>      
</body>
</html>
```

Register.php

---

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>User registration form- PHP MySQL Ligin System | W3Epic.com</title>
</head>
<body>  
<h1>User registration form- PHP MySQL Ligin System | W3Epic.com</h1>
<?php
require_once("db_const.php");
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
?>  <!-- The HTML registration form -->
    <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
        Username: <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
        Password: <input type="password" name="password" /><br />
        First name: <input type="text" name="first_name" /><br />
        Last name: <input type="text" name="last_name" /><br />
        Email: <input type="type" name="email" /><br />

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />

    </form>
<?php
} else {
## connect mysql server
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    # check connection
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->connect_errno} : {$mysqli->connect_error}</p>";
        exit();
    }
## query database
    #prepare data for insertion
    $username    = $_POST['username'];
    $password    = $_POST['password'];
    $first_name  = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name   = $_POST['last_name'];
    $email       = $_POST['email'];

    # check if username and email exist else insert
    $exists = 0;
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT username from users WHERE username = '{$username}' LIMIT 1");
    if ($result->num_rows == 1) {
        $exists = 1;
        $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT email from users WHERE email = '{$email}' LIMIT 1");
        if ($result->num_rows == 1) $exists = 2;    
    } else {
        $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT email from users WHERE email = '{$email}' LIMIT 1");
        if ($result->num_rows == 1) $exists = 3;
    }

    if ($exists == 1) echo "<p>Username already exists!</p>";
    else if ($exists == 2) echo "<p>Username and Email already exists!</p>";
    else if ($exists == 3) echo "<p>Email already exists!</p>";
    else {
        # insert data into mysql database
        $sql = "INSERT  INTO `users` (`id`, `username`, `password`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`) 
                VALUES (NULL, '{$username}', '{$password}', '{$first_name}', '{$last_name}', '{$email}')";

        if ($mysqli->query($sql)) {
            //echo "New Record has id ".$mysqli->insert_id;
            echo "<p>Registred successfully!</p>";
        } else {
            echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->errno} : {$mysqli->error}</p>";
            exit();
        }
    }
}
?>      
</body>
</html>
```

DB_const.php

---

```
<?php
# mysql db constants 
    const DB_HOST = 'localhost';
    const DB_USER = 'root';
    const DB_PASS = '';
    const DB_NAME = 'php_mysql_login_system';
?>
```

Comment: You haven't specified an exact problem, or provided any examples of what you have tried to resolve the issue you are experiencing?

Comment: as i said, I'm a beginner. I know of a few ways i can do this that might work. but what i find on the web is hard for me to understand. I think i can

1Session start and cookies, Making the homepage the login page.
2Make the php variables global

Comment: _"I know of a few ways i can do this that might work"_ - do what though exactly?

Comment: Make my login scripts work through all the pages... so i can log in and sign up on any page. Sorry im not good with questions

Comment: I see.. If I'm honest as you say you are _"only just beginning to learn how to program"_ I would recommend not taking on such a heavy duty project and start with the basics of client-side and server-side web development. This question is far too broad to be able to provide a reasonable answer and explanation, without simply developing the code for you. Apologies.

Comment: Beginner or not - there is totally no need for the (bad) language in your code.  Have some respect - you are asking for help here.

Comment: Just a heads up that "2Make the php variables global" is a terrible idea.  If any of the tutorials you have use `global` for anything, stop using them.

Comment: Would you mind editing the question to make clear _what you want to happen_? Describe what this does now, and what you want it to do, and you'll be much more likely to get a constructive answer.

Comment: You should follow a structured method for learning, rather posting a vague doubt (not even including a question mark!). [Here you find some material](http://www.phptherightway.com/).

Comment: @moonwave99 that's a great link, but note that the OP said he is "only just beginning to learn how to program." That link is aimed at people with experience in other languages, based on the introduction "aims to give seasoned pros..." You might want to suggest something more basic

Comment: I've seen some language in code before and sometimes it's warranted/funny/whatever but there's no need for that to filter through here. If your automatic reaction is to use that string for testing yourself - fine. If you're posting code here, please kindly remove it.

Comment: Sorry about the Profanity i went through to see if i did anything and i missed this :(

Comment: Pro tip - never put something like that **anywhere** in code (including comments/server side scripts). You just never know when someone will see that...

Comment: Yeah, I know for the future.... also this is how i would learn, do a project from start to finish... its the only way for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking your code, and focusing on the SESSION, hashed passwords, db. And not the  few lines of getting mysqli bindings with parameters for now, or css, etc, I leave you with the following:

**index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();  // Start or resume the session
  if ($_POST['logout_yeehaw']) 
  { // form has been submitted to self from Logout button
    $_SESSION['proceed']=0; // bye bye, pseudo logout (true, you could kill all at once, please forgive)
    $_SESSION['userId']=-1;
    $_SESSION['fn']="";
  else 
  {
  } 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
  .box{
    background-color: #d3d3d3;
    border: 1px solid grey;
  }

</style>

  </head>
  <body>
<?php 
include "showLoginStatus.php";
?>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a href="" class="navbar-brand">Insanity and Calamity</a>
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="">Andrew</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Tommy</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Jayme</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav pull-right">
            <li><a href="register.php">Register</a></li>
            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
            <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 box">Holy cow cool</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 box">Holy cow cool</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 box">Holy super cool</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 box">Holy super cool</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
session_start();    // Start or resume the session
$bailOutGoHome = '<script type="text/javascript">';
$bailOutGoHome .= 'window.location = "'. "index.php".'"';
$bailOutGoHome .= '</script>';
$_SESSION['proceed']=0; // bye bye, pseudo logout (true, you could kill all at once, please forgive)
$_SESSION['userId']=-1;
$_SESSION['fn']="";
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>User Login Form - PHP MySQL Login System | W3Epic.com</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="index.php" >Home</a>
<h1>User Login Form - PHP MySQL Login System | W3Epic.com</h1>
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])){
?>
<!-- The HTML login form -->
<div style="background-color: #EDB495">You have just been logged out if you were logged in.</div>
    <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
        Username: <input type="text" name="username" />
        Password: <input type="password" name="password" />

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
<?php
} else {
    require_once("db_const.php");
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    # check connection
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->connect_errno} : {$mysqli->connect_error}</p>";
        exit();
    }

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // no way man, we don't LIKE the next line at all !
    //$sql = "SELECT userId,email from appusers WHERE username LIKE '{$username}' AND password LIKE '{$password}' LIMIT 1";
    $sql = "SELECT userId,email,password as dbhashxxx,first_name,last_name from appusers WHERE username ='{$username}' LIMIT 1";

    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows == 1) {
        echo "1";
        $row = $result->fetch_array();
        $dbHash=$row['dbhashxxx'];
        if (password_verify($password, $dbHash)) {
            // password is valid, set some session stuff and leave to index.php
            $_SESSION['proceed']=1;
            $_SESSION['userId']=$row['userId'];
            $_SESSION['fn']=$row['first_name'] ." ". $row['last_name'];
            echo $bailOutGoHome;    // go home (index.php) avoids "headers already sent error"
        }       
    }
    // leave them stranded here, to slow down their robot
    echo "<p>Invalid username/password combination. You are evil, now go away.</p>";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**register.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>User registration form- PHP MySQL Login System | W3Epic.com</title>
</head>
<body> 
<a href="index.php" >Home</a> 
<h1>User registration form- PHP MySQL Login System | W3Epic.com</h1>
<?php
require_once("db_const.php");
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
?>  <!-- The HTML registration form -->
    <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
        Username: <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
        Password: <input type="password" name="password" /><br />
        First name: <input type="text" name="first_name" /><br />
        Last name: <input type="text" name="last_name" /><br />
        Email: <input type="type" name="email" /><br />

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />
    </form>
<?php
} else {
## connect mysql server
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    # check connection
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->connect_errno} : {$mysqli->connect_error}</p>";
        exit();
    }
## query database
    #prepare data for insertion
    $username    = $_POST['username'];
    $password    = $_POST['password'];
    $first_name  = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name   = $_POST['last_name'];
    $email       = $_POST['email'];

    # check if username and email exist else insert
    $exists = 0;
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT username from appusers WHERE username = '{$username}' LIMIT 1");
    if ($result->num_rows == 1) {
        $exists = 1;
        $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT email from appusers WHERE email = '{$email}' LIMIT 1");
        if ($result->num_rows == 1) $exists = 2;    
    } else {
        $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT email from appusers WHERE email = '{$email}' LIMIT 1");
        if ($result->num_rows == 1) $exists = 3;
    }

    if ($exists == 1) echo "<p>Username already exists!</p>";
    else if ($exists == 2) echo "<p>Username and Email already exists!</p>";
    else if ($exists == 3) echo "<p>Email already exists!</p>";
    else {

        // see http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php
        $options = [
            'cost' => 12,   // let's splurge
        ];
        $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);    // change to suit your concerns

        # insert data into mysql database
        # let the DB do the autoincrement of userId, don't pass NULL as 1st parameter
        $sql = "INSERT  INTO `appusers` (`username`, `password`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`) 
                VALUES ('{$username}', '{$hash}', '{$first_name}', '{$last_name}', '{$email}')";

        if ($mysqli->query($sql)) {
            //echo "New Record has id ".$mysqli->insert_id;
            echo "<p>Registered successfully!</p>";
        } else {
            echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->errno} : {$mysqli->error}</p>";
            exit();
        }
    }
}
?>      
</body>
</html>
```

**showLoginStatus.php**

```
<?php 
if ($_SESSION['proceed']==1) {
  echo "<div style=\"background-color: #A2ED95\">";
  echo "You are logged in. Welcome ".$_SESSION['fn'].", userId=".$_SESSION['userId'];

  echo "<form method=post action=\"". $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ."\">";  
  echo "<input type=hidden name=logout_yeehaw value=1>";
  echo "<input type='submit' name='logout' value='Logout' />";
  echo "</form></div>"; 
}
else
  echo "<div style=\"background-color: #EDB495\">You are not logged in.</div>";
```

**db_const.php**

```
<?php
# mysql db constants 
    const DB_HOST = 'localhost';
    const DB_USER = 'dbuser1';
    const DB_PASS = 'newpassword';
    const DB_NAME = 'login_system';
?>
```

**random db stuff:**

```
create database login_system;
use login_system;
-- drop table appusers;
create table appusers
(   -- does not care about saving user SALT
    -- remember that the cleartext password, the cost, and SALT are ALL baked into hash
    -- so as far as I am concerned, the SALT is a throw-away, after user one-time gen of it
    userId int auto_increment primary key,
    username varchar(20) not null,
    password varchar(255) not null, -- the hash, maybe blowfish, maybe not, look at code
    first_name varchar(50) not null,
    last_name varchar(50) not null,
    email varchar(100) not null
);
-- truncate table appusers;
-- note : despite the below, cleartext passwords will not be used
insert appusers(username,password,first_name,last_name,email) values ('andrew','cleartext','andrew','smith','andrew@gmail.com');

select * from appusers;
+--------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------+------------+------------+-----------------+
| userId | username | password                                                     | first_name | last_name  | email           |
+--------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------+------------+------------+-----------------+
|      1 | user1    | $2y$11$mp34MpHbhAcbN5YVlUBh4eTv0HMxuJJbvWhFKdtfkMDyhJpwnBCpG | Fred       | Gibbons    | f@g.com         |
|      2 | user2    | $2y$11$8dkjzLghFqU4nXSPPFdsa.nLvlw.EvdgxvYe5FbGsB7mx4BBRAqwy | Kelly      | Hartshorne | kelly@gmail.com |
|      3 | user3    | $2y$12$rk66cxOSRLUjIDKVU2EFq.Zz8T06qdEuzC4i3lKAi84IpGSKcGV8. | joe        | schmoe     | j               |
+--------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------+------------+------------+-----------------+   

create user 'dbuser1'@'localhost' identified by 'newpassword';
select user,host,password from mysql.user where user='dbuser1';
+---------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
| user    | host      | password                                  |
+---------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
| dbuser1 | localhost | *Fxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx |
+---------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
grant all on login_system.* to 'dbuser1'@'localhost';
```

Comment: Thank you very much, when i return to this task it will help a lot xD I've since decided on focusing on front end bootstrap for a bit and slowly bring myself into php mysql more. But this will help and thanks for the notes too!